# CustomControl inherited from DataGridColumn: problems with styling

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to write a DataGridSeparatorColumn custom control, inherited from DataGridColumn, forcing it to be 2 pixels wide and have a black background.

```
public class DataGridSeparatorColumn : DataGridColumn
{
    public DataGridSeparatorColumn()
    {
        CanUserReorder = false;
        CanUserResize = false;
        CanUserSort = false;

        MaxWidth = 2;
        MinWidth = 2;

        IsReadOnly = true;

        Header = "";

        // TODO: Set black background and/or other visual stuff here                

    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        //return new FrameworkElement();
        return null;
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        //return new FrameworkElement();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I googled all around to find a sample for the TODO-code but I havent found anything useful. Can anyone point me the right way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Style myStyle = new Style();
Setter myBlackBackgroundSetter = new Setter();
myBlackBackgroundSetter.Property = DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty;
myBlackBackgroundSetter.Value = Brushes.Black;
myStyle.Setters.Add(myBlackBackgroundSetter);
CellStyle = myStyle;
```

Comment: PS: if you want the column's Header to have the black colour as well, then you can do a similar thing by setting DataGridColumnHeader.BackgroundProperty and then the HeaderStyle of the column.

Comment: It works for the `HeaderStyle` but not for `CellStyle`: the header cell has black background as expected but the cells are not.

Comment: I guess as Eirik says, you'll have to set a margin of -2 as well. Otherwise the black background can't be seen because the cell is so narrow.

Answer (score 1):

bobsmith is on the right track, but you need to adjust the Margin (and possibly Padding) properties for the color cover the entire cell.

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.MarginProperty, new Thickness(-2.0)));

CellStyle = style;
```

-2.0 might not be the perfect value for your case, so try different values here until you're satisfied.

Comment: Well, I would say that my answer was not meant to be a complete solution to OP's requirement, just a pointer in the right direction; StackOverflow is all about guidance and understanding, not about other people doing your work for you! But fair enough, anyway.